# Facebook facial recognition functionality with java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to start a java application using facebook facial recognition, but first I need to know if it is possible...

More specific: is there a way to get the tags suggestions of facebook passing a photo to a WS provided by them or something similar?

I've been searching in facebook developers section, but I haven't found anything related..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain Facebook has not exposed any kind of API related to facial recognition. They got rid of Face.com's API (Face.com was the company Facebook acquired to add their facial recognition functionality).

Given the legal and political tension Facebook has dealt with related to the fact they have this capability, I don't see them exposing it to others just yet. I think they want people to become cooler with the idea, which may take time, before they even consider doing so.

Comment: well, that's reasonable...
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Face.com api is based on OpenCV and java api for OpenCV is available